# how to copy the lists dynamically through a loop

Tags: r

I am trying to copy a list to a list dynamically in R.

I have a list `query`.

I also have lists like `query1`, `query2`,.., `queryn`.

I am trying to copy the contents of `query1` to `queryn` to query dynamically through a for a loop.

The copy function is working if I keep `query=copy(query1)`.

```
for j in 1 to n
{
query = copy(paste(query,j,sep='')
some calculations
}
```

However, the above for loop is not working.

Could you please help me with the R code?

Comment: It's not totally clear from your post what you are asking. I think that what you're struggling with is getting access to the jth query list at each iteration of the loop, right? If that's the case try `get(paste('query',j,sep=''))`

Comment: A small example would with sample input and desired output would make this much clearer.